# Protractor - Finding elements by any attribute

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, css-selectors, protractor

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li ui-sref-active="active">
        <a class="ng-scope" translate="menu.home" href="#/home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li ui-sref-active="active">
        <a class="ng-scope" ui-sref="customer.list" translate="menu.customers" href="#/customers">Customers</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to search for the element using the text "Home" as in code below:

```
element(by.linkText("Home")).click();
```

But I need use too any other available attribute, in this case `translate`, to make it more accurate.

Is there any possibility in doing that? I've seen things like this

```
by.css(".ng-scope input[translate='menu.customers']");
```

But it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `by.css(".ng-scope input[translate='menu.customers']");`

This basically translates to: give me the `input` element having `menu.customers` `translate` attribute value, somewhere inside the parent element having `ng-scope` class. This is not working since there is no parent element with `ng-scope` class in the HTML you've provided and it is `a` instead of `input` you are looking for.

Instead, you probably meant to:

```
a.ng-scope[translate='menu.customers']
```

Though, I would not recommend relying on the quite broad `ng-scope` class.

---

Here are several rather precise CSS selectors, given the HTML you've provided:

```
ul.menu > li > a[href*=home]  // href contains "home"
ul.menu > li > a[href$=home]  // href ends with "home"
ul.menu > li > a[translate="menu.home"]  // translate equals to "menu.home"
ul.menu > li > a[translate$=home]  // translate contains "home"
```